# Is it possible to create a class method that would return an array or nothing at all depending on a given condition?

Tags: java, matrix, multidimensional-array

Through my humble experience in programming I can tell with 90% certainty that it would not be possible to do such a thing. However I know that you guys out there are more experienced than me and thus have better and more elegant solutions to my problem.

Here is my question: 
I have made a class method to check for matrix addition or subtraction compatibility. It returns true if two given matrices are compatible for addition or subtraction. My next method is addMatrices which takes two matrices as follows:

`double [][] addMatrices(double matA [][], double matB[][])`

so the method return a 2d array here is my code solution:

```
double [][] addMatrices(double A [][], double B[][]){
      double reusltMat;
      if(AddSubComp(A,B){
         resultMat= new double [A.getRows][A.getCols];
          //getRows returns the # of crows 
         for (int i=0;i<A.getRows;i++)
             for(int j= 0;j<A.getCols;j++)
                 reslutMat[i][j]=A[i][j]+B[i][j];
          return resultMat;
       else 
           System.out.println("Out of boundaries");
       resultMat= new double[0][0];
       return resultMat;
```

so my question is there any possible way to avoid initialising the resultMat if the `if (statement)`is false? so that I return a 2D array IFF the addition is compatible i.e the two given matrices are of the same dimensions.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: you may return `null`

Comment: You still have to return *something* (unless you throw an exception).  What would you want to return in this case?

Comment: [`java.util.Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html).

Comment: Note that your parens and braces are all over the place. That code won't compile. Usually best to at least post syntactically-valid code (unless asking a syntax question). Also **strongly** recommend consistently using braces, not doing the "Oh, it's a single statement, I don't need them" thing.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth so can i just throw an exception without returning anything? i am not that good with exception.

Comment: @HannahMckay You're welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you tried returning null?

```
double[][] reusltMat = null;
```

After the *else*

```
return resultMat;
```

Comment: Returning `null` is not a great strategy here - you'll either end up with NPEs downstream, or a ton of null-handling logic everywhere.

Comment: Her code will end up returning null unless she use another type as response.

Comment: Or unless it throws an exception (which seems reasonable - attempting to add two differently-sized matrices is an error).

Comment: @Hannah you can throw exceptions any time. But the question is. Can your code ends w.o a result? Should you break up the execution bc your code could not generate any result? If your code can end up w.o result then return null. If not... Throw exception. But you need to know what to do after that exception... Catch? Let it go? ... Etc

Comment: @Laiv i just noticed that returning null isnt the greatest idea there is because imagine a situation where your client programmer is using your API and she/he is expecting an array back from invoking this method as follows:
`double array[][]= (addMatrices(A,B));`right, lets suppose that they have no clue about Matrix operation they will then end up with an array that is = null and once they for loop to print it out they will end up with issues that they have no clue about.

Comment: So if you want to prevent API consumers, the code you proposed is ok. An empty array. API often returns empty collections. Check out Arrays.class. Now lets go further. Is an empty array a valid answer? Does it make sense? Or shall we let know to de API user that there was a problem impossible to get rid of it?

Comment: @Laiv Thank you a lot for your help :) and thank you everyone who attempted to help. You guys are great

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use the `Optional` introduced in Java 8. It is built for such cases. Returning `null` is not the best solution particularly in view of the ugly `nullpointer exception`s that arise because of it.

See here : [Java 8 Optional](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/java8-optional-2175753.html).
Ask me if you need anything else.

Comment: u r welcome.  Let me know if you need anything else :)

Comment: Thank you again for your offer to help. Hmm i was thinking is it possible to use the enhanced for loop to set elements of the array to somethling. Suppose i am given an `arrayA` with values and and i am asked to create another array `B`in which only the non-zero values from `arrayA` are to be stored? is it possible to achieve using the `for-each loop`? Appreciate your help